# How do i remove/strip specific string in java

Tags: java, android, string, replace, strip

From AWS SNS I am reciving following response in my android app

```
{default={"messageType": "WRITE"}}
```

I need to achieve this and I can assign the above response only to either **String** or **String** datatype variable

```
{"messageType": "WRITE"}
```

So how do I achieve this?

Comment: this is not a correct format to get response

Comment: use String.substring()

Comment: What is the type of the response you are getting? {default={"messageType": "WRITE"}} is it a String?

Comment: This is an odd format. You can `split` the String on `=` and then remove the last character.

Comment: replace the "=" character with ":" and convert the string to json format

Comment: @SaravInfern  replacing "=" with ":" made sense..!! Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use String.substring() to do it :

```
String stringSource = "{default={\"messageType\": \"WRITE\"}}";
String newString = stringSource.substring(9, stringSource.length() - 1);
System.out.println(newString);
```